# STOP after RETURN in bytecode generated by solidity

Tags: solidity, bytecode

I am currently analyzing the code generated by the solidity compiler. Let's take this simple example:

```
pragma solidity^0.4.24;
contract test {
    constructor() public { }
}
```

The code generated with [REMIX IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org) (with compiler
(`version:0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.Emscripten.clang`) (after removing the 43 bytes of SWARM hash) is the following one:

```
PUSH1 0x80
PUSH1 0x40
MSTORE
CALLVALUE
DUP1
ISZERO
PUSH1 0xF
JUMPI
PUSH1 0x0
DUP1
REVERT
JUMPDEST
POP
PUSH1 0x35
DUP1
PUSH1 0x1D
PUSH1 0x0
CODECOPY
PUSH1 0x0
**RETURN**
**STOP**
PUSH1 0x80
PUSH1 0x40
MSTORE
PUSH1 0x0
DUP1
**REVERT**
**STOP**
```

In the yellow paper it is specified that return opcode halts the execution. Why would one also call stop after return?

Comment: With what exact version of the compiler is it?

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab, thank you, please see my edit ^^

Comment: I can reproduce, and I see `00` at the end of the constructor and at the end of the deployed code.

Comment: 00 is the number for the opcode STOP. Do you mean that in this case it shall be interpreted as a number and not as an opcode?

Comment: I don't know. By `00` I indeed meant `STOP`, sorry I wasn't clear. Not sure why the compiler would play "belt and braces"...